# jQuery update label's text with HTML string

Tags: jquery

I have a simple HTML `label` input. By using the ajax request, I get back the HTML string which I want to put as that label's text. To do so, I try the following code:

```
$('#my-label').text($("<label class='someClass'>4.00 ABC</label> (13.26 DEF)"));
```

but nothing happens. How to cope with that ?

Comment: What part of the `label.someClass` do you want in `#my-label`? Do you want to wrap the labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.html()`

```
$('#my-label').html("<label class='someClass'>4.00 ABC</label> (13.26 DEF)");
```

Although I'm not sure what `#my-label` is supposed to be in your case ..

Edit: If it is the id of the label itself as PRPGFerret suggested, a better approach would be:

```
$('#my-label').text('4.00 ABC').addClass('someClass');
```

Comment: I would assume the ID of the label tag :P

Comment: is this someClass allready existing in your markup? so you could write `$('label.someClass').text('4.00 ABC');`